# WMIC mystery - why is this query invalid?

Tags: wmi

Why is this an invalid query?

```
wmic service where 'caption like "%documentum%"' get name, caption  

Node - PE95AOECM  
ERROR:  
Description = Invalid query
```

This is the expected output:

```
Caption                                 Name  
EMC Documentum Thumbnail Server         DctmThumbnailServer  
Documentum Docbroker Service Docbroker  DmDocbroker  
Documentum Java Method Server           DmMethodServer  
Documentum Docbase Service KxKDOC_DEV   DmServerKxKDOC_DEV  
Documentum Docbase Service KxKTAX_DEV   DmServerKxKTAX_DEV  
Documentum Docbase Service KxK_Dev      DmServerKxK_Dev  
Documentum Docbase Service KxK_Dev_HRP  DmServerKxK_Dev_HRP  
Documentum Docbase Service KxK_Dev_TAX  DmServerKxK_Dev_TAX
```

If I modify the query slightly I do in fact get a valid response similar to the above:

removed the first %

```
wmic service where 'caption like "documentum%"' get name, caption
```

added a space after documentum

```
wmic service where 'caption like "%documentum %"' get name, caption
```

removed the last m of documentum

```
wmic service where 'caption like "%documentu%"' get name, caption
```

and as an example of a similar case where I query for the first word of a multi-word caption is successful

```
wmic service where 'caption like "%group%"' get name, caption  

Caption              Name  
Group Policy Client  gpsvc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an `echo wmic service where 'caption like "%documentum%"' get name, caption` and you can see what's going on. You can also do `echo %documentum%`.

(It should echo the exact command back, including the `%documentum%`)

Maybe you have an **environment variable** named **`documentum`**.
(environment variables have precedence over the command parameters. So if they are present, they get substituted.)

You can do `set documentum=` and then execute the line to empty the variable (if set).

Comment: Brilliant. That's exactly what was going on. documentum is an env.var.